# Grub menu is not showed after installing arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, grub

I'm trying to install Arch Linux for the first time in dual boot with Windows, but faced with the small problem. I'm trying to setup GRUB but when I start the PC, Windows loads without the GRUB menu ever displayed. I tried some solutions from the internet, but none of them helped me.

Here's what I tried to do:

1. I mounted root partition

   ```bash
   mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt
   ```
2. I mounted EFI partition

   ```sh
   mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/efi
   ```
3. I logged in to the system

   ```sh
   arch-root /mnt
   ```
4. I installed grub

   ```sh
   grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/efi/ --bootloader-id=GRUB
   ```
5. And generated grub config

   ```sh
   grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

So here is what installer generated and here's nothing about windows:

```sh
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod btrfs
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod btrfs
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a
    echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a rw  loglevel=3 quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Arch Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a' {
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod btrfs
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux (fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-fallback-e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod btrfs
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=e5bb549c-2301-4d33-a4ca-f7be8fa28d1a rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
  insmod bli
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/25_bli ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
    fwsetup --is-supported
    if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
        menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
            fwsetup
        }
    fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Then I also tried to uncomment line in `/etc/default/grub`

```sh
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

Did the same things but it didn't detect Windows anyway. Here's the message I received after generating GRUB config:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot:  initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

But result is the same.

Also, here's all my partitions:

```
Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1023999    1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1024000    1228799     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1228800    1261567      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4    1261568 1409193983 1407932416 671.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1952376832 1953521663    1144832   559M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1409193984 1948162047  538968064   257G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 1948162048 1952376831    4214784     2G Linux swap
```

And Windows boot is located at `/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot` directory.

Here's the result of `efibootmgr` command

```
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0004,0001
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,da178692-f29b-4f3d-acbf-e3259f35817a,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\GRUBX64.EFI)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000061000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,da178692-f29b-4f3d-acbf-e3259f35817a,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)0000424f
Boot0005* UEFI:  USB DISK 2.0 PMAP, Partition 1 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(6,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x36f5a9fc,0x800,0x39d1800)0000424f
```

So if you know what can be the problem, please tell me.

Comment: Welcome, if GRUB does not even show and Windows boots directly, check the BIOS/UEFI settings of your machine, the Windows bootloader must be as the first boot option.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Thanks for answer, yeah, I checked it and windows boot manager is on the first place. But it is the disk where the arch linux is installed also, I can't swithc to another option.

Comment: UEFI boot entries are not per disk, you can have one disk and many entries. You can't switch because there's no other option, or there is but something else happens? You can use `efibootmgr` to check UEFI entries, it can be run from a live Linux.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Well, I don't know why, but there is no other options except windows. I updated my question with result if ```efibootmgr``` command

Comment: What is the content of `/efi/` folder? Do you see GRUB EFI files? What happens if you rename or move out Windows' EFI files? Did you try to mount the Windows system partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p4`)?